# react redux and combine reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hello I am using thunks to get data from my backend
but I am unsure how to do it in my combine reducer

**my types:**

```
export const FETCH_SUCESS = 'FETCH_SUCESS';
export const FETCH_FAIL = 'FETCH_FAIL';
export const FETCH_LOADING = 'FETCH_FAIL';
export const FILTER_PRODUCT = 'FILTER_PRODUCT';
```

**my action:**

```
    import api from '../../services/api';
    import {FETCH_SUCESS,FETCH_FAIL,FETCH_LOADING} from '../constants/fetchTypes';

    const fetchSucess = data => ({
        type: FETCH_SUCESS,
        payload: {
          ...data
        }
      });

      const fetchStarted = () => ({
        type: FETCH_LOADING
      });

      const fetchFailed = error => ({
        type: FETCH_FAIL,
        payload: {
          error
        }
      });

    export const fetchProduct = () => {
      console.log('action')
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(fetchStarted());

      api
        .get('/products')
        .then(res => {
          dispatch(fetchSucess(res.data));
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch(fetchFailed(err.message));
        });
    };
  };
```

**my reducer:**

```
import {
    FETCH_SUCESS,
    FETCH_FAIL,
    FETCH_LOADING,
  } from '../constants/fetchTypes';

  const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    error: null
  };

  export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true
        };
      case FETCH_SUCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          data: [...state.data, action.payload]
        };
      case FETCH_FAIL:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.payload.error
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

**my combiner:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import  productReducer from './productsFetch.reducer';

export default combineReducers({

});
```

**my store:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}
```

**my home.js**

```
class HomeProducts extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData();
      }
    render() {
      const productItems = this.props.products.map( product => (
          <div className="col-md-4 pt-4 pl-2">
          <div className = "thumbnail text-center"> 
          <a href={`#${product.id}`}  onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>
              <p>
                  {product.name}
              </p>
          </a>
          </div>
              <b>{util.formatCurrency(product.price)}</b>
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
      )
      )
        return (
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                {productItems}
            </div>  
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        console.log(state);
  };
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchProduct())
    };
  };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeProducts);
```

I have doubt what to use in my combiner

to get the date and the mistakes How I have my loading,data, error

I don't know how I will do it in meu combine `redux`

I also don't know if I had the best practices in my `action` and my `reducer`

Comment: have initialized the basic store? if so, you can simply add `productReducer` which you imported in the combiner file as a _key_ in the object you are passing to the `combineReducers` function.

Comment: @Sultan H. yes i start store

Comment: i go edit with my store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your combiner file just add your reducers as key value pairs like so:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import  productReducer from './productsFetch.reducer';
// import anotherReducer from './yourPath';

export default combineReducers({
    products: productReducer,
 // anotherState: anotherReducer
});
```

Ideally you should import your actions and pass it your component through your connect method like so then you will be able to access it from your component as props.

```
import fetchProduct from './pathToYourActionFile';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
};

const mapActionsToProps = {
    fetchProduct: fetchProduct
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(HomeProducts);
```

Comment: Oops thanks bro for some reason not calling my action could you see where I went wrong?

Comment: You mean `this.props.fetchData`?

Comment: Yes for some reason my state is coming as null

Comment: productReducer: {loading: false, data: Array(0), error: null}

Even my api working normally, but it's not going in my action

Comment: share the code for `fetchProduct()`. Also that is not how you dispatch actions if you are using `redux-thunk`

Comment: Yes I am using thunks,
I already posted the code is my action:


  export const fetchProduct = () => {
      console.log('action')
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(fetchStarted());
        
      api
        .get('/products')
        .then(res => {
          dispatch(fetchSucess(res.data));
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch(fetchFailed(err.message));
        });
    };
  };

Comment: I don't see any `fetchProduct` related code in your post yet you are dispatching it as an action

Comment: I updated now was because I was under another name, but the error continues

Comment: My action function had another name in the post, but I've already changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203596/discussion-between-dragonborn-and-felipe).

Answer (score -1):

```
import thunkInject from 'redux-thunk-inject';

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunkInject()]);
const store = mockStore(mockStore);
const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store} />);
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

to mock a store with thunk, you can inject it as a prop in a component.  Or in a reducer, e.g.

```
import productReducer from '../productReducer';

import {
FETCH_SUCESS,
    FETCH_FAIL,
    FETCH_LOADING,
} from '../constants/fetchTypes';

describe('product reducer', () => {
    it('Should handle FETCH_SUCCESS', () => {
        expect(productReducer(store, FETCH_SUCCESS)
        ).toEqual({
              loading: true
        });

        expect(productReducer(store, FETCH_FAIL).toEqual({
          loading: false,
          error: action.payload.error})
    });
```

Comment: I couldn't understand very well